# floating point while loop

Tags: c, floating-point

```
int main()
{
    float x = 50;
    float y = 1/x;
    float result = y * x;

    float test = 41;
    float z = 1/test;
    float testRes = z * test;


    while (result == 1)
    {    
        x--;
    }

    printf("%f\n", x);
    printf("%.6f\n", testRes);
}
```

My while loop is infinite, it never ends, but it should end at 41 because when I test 41, it equals 0.99999404

Answer (score 3):

`result` never changes within the loop, therefore there is no reason to believe that, once it starts, the loop will *ever* end.

Comment: but won't the result be 0.9999404 when x is 41?

Comment: If `result` is not 1 then the loop will never be entered. If `result` is 1 then the loop will never be exited.

Comment: but when x--; doesn't that mean i go from 50, 49, 48, ..., 41, which doesn't enter the loop, and then since 41 gives 0.999404 41 should be printed?

Comment: Where are you changing `result`?

Comment: from float result = y * x, since x is changing shouldn't result change as well?

Comment: No. Unlike in make or Verilog, execution in C is immediate. The operation is performed before the loop starts, and then never again.

Comment: sorry so how would I get the loop to go to 41 and stop?

Comment: Change `result` inside the loop.

Comment: Also, there's no reason to believe that `x * (1/x)` will equal 1, when using floats. Never base program flow on a floating point test for equality.